# redirect user to play store from my app

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I want to redirect the user to the Google Play Store application from my app, and i want to open the collection of Editor's choice as a default activity of the play store app.

in [Documentation(OpeningCollection)](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningCollection), it says that if you want to open the Editor's choice collection you should use :

```
market://apps/collection/<collection_name>
```

I've tried this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://apps/collection/editors_choice"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it doesn't work , it always give `ActivityNotFoundException` :

```
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market }
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at com.icompagnon.activities.ApplicationsSpaceActivity.onClick(ApplicationsSpaceActivity.java:92)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
06-21 17:23:26.564: W/System.err(1820):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When i try to open the details of some application it works ( example : **google-maps app**):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But when i try to open the editor's choice activity , it returns exception. Is this an issue in Android ??

Comment: What is "the editor's choice activity"? How have you tried to open it? We will also need the stack trace to be able to assist you much further.

Comment: the code in my question is what i'm using to launch google play , refer the docs that i've putted in my question  : http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningCollection

Comment: We still need the stack trace to be able to assist you much further.

Comment: @CommonsWare suggested stack trace will be handy..

Comment: see my edits for the stack trace ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy of the Play Store does not support `market://apps/collection/editors_choice`.

You might try the alternative (`http://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/editors_choice`) to see whether the Play Store comes up as an available option. If it does, then that would suggest a documentation bug, and there's some different syntax for the `market://` version of that `Uri`. If the Play Store does not come up as an option, that would suggest that your edition of the Play Store perhaps pre-dates the addition of support for those `Uri` structures.

Comment: did you tried it on your device?? i've tried in my HTC ONE X with Jelly Bean 4.1.1 , and in Samsung Galaxy S III with ICS 4.0.3 and it doens't work . it looks like a documentation bug ?

Comment: when i've tried the alternative, the Play Store comes up as an Available option. so can we say that would be a documentation bug ?

Comment: @Houcine: Yes. I just downloaded ManifestViewer (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer) and examined the Play Store manifest. The activity that supports `http://play.google.com/store` URLs only supports `market://search` URLs. There is another activity that supports `market://details`, and that's all I see in the `market:` scheme. So, the documentation is out of sync with the current version of the Play Store, it seems.

Comment: Thanks , that's it. and +1 for the app ManifestViewer ;-)

Comment: @Houcine: I used to use another app for inspecting the manifest, but they dropped that feature. Up until today, I had not yet found an alternative. Your question led me to try again, where I found ManifestViewer. So, thank *you* for spurring me to find it! :-)